# Is it possible to get the result code of an intent launched from the command line?

Tags: android-intent

Using `/system/bin/am`, is it possible to determine the result code of an intent which was set using `setResult()`? I've had a look at `am` and can't find a corresponding option.

Comment: Since Android doesn't have a "real shell", I'm not sure.  But the standard "shell exit status" command is "$?".  EXAMPLE: `am myintent;echo $?`

Comment: @paulsm4: I think that am's return code is not the intent result code.